# Excel is changing (12.3%) to -12.3% when I save a .csv file

Tags: r, excel, csv, format

I've been formatting data in R to automate the process of formatting a table for a manuscript. This means that I've been less concerned with tidy data and analysis and more concerned with getting the bits and pieces of a data frame where I want them. I formatted my data frame in R to look like this (more or less):

```
            screening                  Disease_2015
1               Total                (n = 12,345)
2            Screened                     12,345
3    Screened_Percent                     (12.3%)
4            Positive                      1,234
5        Positive_Pct                       1.2%

write.csv (table, "U:\\My Documents\\Table.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I'm mostly concerned about the parentheses in row 3. They show up in the data frame in R, but not in Excel. This is the code I was using to add them in to specific columns.

```
addparentheses <- function(x){paste("(", x, ")", sep = "")}

Table$column <- addparentheses(Table$column)
```

When I open the file in excel to make some finishing touches, it shows up in this format:
[image: Table from excel]

I've done this process with a few other data frames and this is the first time that it is replacing the () with a -. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Wrapping values in parenthesis is a common way to denote negative values. What is your intention besides negatives when wrapping in parenthesis?

Comment: Do you need the cells to be non-text format? If not, then format column B as text while importing into Excel. That will prevent () changing to negatives.

Comment: I would like to avoid importing it from Excel because it does not allow me to merge table values for some reason.

Comment: My intention is to just portray a percentage in parentheses. It's primarily for aesthetic reasons after I manually adjust some other things. I think it hasn't automatically corrected it before because I had the (percentage) in the same cell with another data value. But I'd now like to keep it in a discrete cell with the parentheses unchanged. Any thoughts?

Comment: Either import it as text; or custom format the cell.